# CSS Bootstrap Equal Height 3 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a vertical menu that fits 100% height. Inside this I need the rows to be equal height stretched to fit this container. Also, having the button seems to drop the container below the page slightly. Is there any way to fix this without positioning the .button class to be absolute?

http://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/Bek9L/2943/

```
<div class="button"><button>Mobile Menu</button></div>
<div class="mobileContainer">
<div class="mobileInner">
    <div class="row nopadding">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">
            <div class="box">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for the equal height problem would be to separate the cells in 3 rows using containers and setting a height of 33% for each one (or 33.3% if you'd like). To make it work the parent container for the rows need a height of 100%.

About the container being dropped: when the browser computes the height of the elements its getting this result:

```
TotalHeight = (Height of the .button div) + (Height of the .mobileContainer div)
TotalHeight = (around 50px) + (100% of the parent container) = MORE than 100%
```

So, basically you're getting a height greater than the one that is available (100%), that's why the browser shows a scrollbar. There are some ways to fix this, one of them being to set a fixed height for the .button div and define the height of your .mobileContainer like this:

```
height: calc(100% - fixed height of the .button div)
```

With that definition you're making sure that the total height is always 100%.

I've modified your Fiddle to show both solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/zrdoze15/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works great. Basically it's going to be used for a mobile navigation. So it will slide up and down on button click. This should work and adjust to mobile screens yes?

Comment: The height is dynamic so mobile screens shoulnd't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height with jquery and put a parent `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">` to each `col-md-6` to preserve a order

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    _height = $(window).height();    
    _innerheight = _height/3
    $(".respheight").height(_innerheight);
    $(".box").height(_innerheight);
    /*the border radius has 1px because is the difference between in the lines*/
});
```

check the 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank_ivan/rom9e7bm/)